# tensorflowjs module cann't be compiled correctly

Tags: javascript

```
$ npm show @tensorflow/tfjs version
$ 1.0.0
$ npm show typescript version
$ 3.4.3
```

when I compile the project `ng serve`, it always gets the errors as below:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs- 
core/dist/io/browser_files.d.ts(24,34): error TS1039: Initializers are not 
allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/browser_http.d.ts(23,31): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/indexed_db.d.ts(31,34): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/local_storage.d.ts(41,34): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-data/dist/dataset.d.ts(235,39): error TS1039: 
Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(29,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(48,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(56,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(64,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(69,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(77,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/activations.d.ts(85,33): error 
TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

why there is another `tensorflow` module:

```
$npm show tensorflow version
$0.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I believe it's the issue with tensorflowjs latest version.
I have it working using the following versions.

```
"@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd": "0.1.1",
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "0.14.0",
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
"typescript": "~2.7.2"
```